# How can I draw flow chart using LaTeX?

Tags: latex

How can I draw flow chart using LaTeX?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/723/how-to-typeset-flowcharts-in-latex

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[Tikz](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) is a good graphics library to do this (directly in Latex), [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/) is an example of a flowchart made with it.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's not strictly using LaTeX, but the [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) suite of tools is pretty neat.

From the description:

> The Graphviz layout programs take descriptions of graphs in a simple text language, and make diagrams in several useful formats such as images and SVG for web pages, Postscript for inclusion in PDF or other documents; or display in an interactive graph browser. (Graphviz also supports GXL, an XML dialect.)

Because the tools are command-line driven, there are ways to include Graphviz graphs in-line in LaTeX files, such as [dot2texi](http://www.fauskes.net/nb/introducing-dot2texi/).

Comment: Graphviz can be used directly from MATLAB through its Java API

Comment: Yeah, and what exactly has matlab to do with latex?

Comment: And what has Graphviz to do with LaTeX?

Answer (score 0):

On CTAN exists a package [nassflow](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nassflow). The [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nassflow/flow_man.pdf) contains an example on page 5.

The package is from 1997, but I was able to use it without problems with TeXLive 2012. It is not part of the TeXLive distribution (wrong license), so you must install it manual. For a quick test, just [download everything](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nassflow) in a directory and try it.